# simple "this" issue with JavaScript fundamentals

Tags: javascript

```
var name = 'Mike';
var person = {
  name: 'John',
  welcome: function(){
    var name = 'Mary';
    return 'Hi ' + this.name;
  }
}

//person.welcome(); 
// output is
// Hi John
// I was expecting output to be
// Hi Mary

person.welcome.call();
// output is
// Hi Mike
// In this case since no argument is passed to call so this is window and 
// I get that window.name is Mike
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var name = 'Mike';
var person = {
  name: 'John',
  welcome: function(){
    var name = 'Mary';
    return 'Hi ' + this.name;
  }
}
```

`this.name` refers to the object property "name"

`name` refers to the variable "name"

You would get the expected result with `return 'Hi ' + name;`

Comment: this.name will be public while just var name will make private JS variable

Answer (score 0):

Why were you expecting `Hi Mary` in the first case?

```
var name = 'Mary';
```

Doesn't overwrite `this.name`, but rather creates a local variable named `name` in the function.

In the second case, you are using `call`, which takes a `this` argument, and:

> Determines the value of this inside
>   fun. If thisArg is null or undefined,
>   this will be the global object.

[From here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/call).

Answer (score 0):

If you are waiting the output to be `Hi Mary` then you do not need to use this in the welcome function. This should do it:

```
var name = 'Mike';
var person = {
  name: 'John',
  welcome: function(){
    var name = 'Mary';
    return 'Hi ' + name;
  }
}
```

When you do `person.welcome()` the `this` keyword references `person`, so on the `welcome` function `this.name` would become `person.name` which is John.

Answer (score 0):

`this` always refers to the object you are calling the function from. In most simple cases this would be whatever is in front of the `.`. For example, in the case of `person.welcome()` this now refers to person. If you call `person.welcome.call()` this refers to the window, because you did not specify anything as a parameter to `call()`.